# Cant run the test class "No tests found with test runner 'Junit5'"

Tags: junit5

I've created a simple Maven java application in which I am trying to run the Test case.

**when doing run as JunitTestCase it gives a popup window stating that** *"No tests found with test runner 'JUnit5'"*.

**and on **console****:

> 

```
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/TestEngine
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.loadTestEngines(ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.java:35)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:87)
>   at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:67)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.<init>(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine  at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)     ... 14 more
```

**my pom.xml has :**

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**as well as using:** `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

**PS:-** I am already using JUnit5 annotations.
and with "Run as maven-test" zero tests were run is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only depend on the api, giving you e.g. the annotations, but you are missing the engine to execute your tests. Either add `junit-jupiter-engine` as dependency or switch to the convenience dependency `junit-jupiter`.

Look at the maven starter sample (https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.7.1/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven), on how to get a minimal functional pom.xml for junit5.